# Importing multiple XML files into R

Tags: xml, database, r, file

What is the best way to concatenate multiple XML files into a single file?

I was thinking of using concatenate in the directory first (working on Mac/Terminal using cat), but then realised this would repeat the root note/header so would break things.

Comment: To the person who silently downvoted: This is the [summer of love](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/), so I suggest you do one of a few things 1) Explain why the downvote, 2) Explain to the OP how to improve the question 3) Edit the question so it is a good question.

Comment: A wild guess: The **XML** package may be of some use.